# Controlling the vertical spacing between two lines

Tags: vertical-spacing

I would like to have the ability to control the vertical separation between `#2` and `#3`. What can I do ?  I do not intend that this functionality includes any nested lists or centred environments, that would misalign `#3`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\dkmKtlog}{ O{0.3cm} m m }
  {
    \begingroup
      \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
      \setlength{\leftskip}{#1}
      \hspace*{-\leftskip}
      \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\normalfont\bfseries [#2]}\par
      \nopagebreak\ignorespaces #3\par
    \endgroup
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\dkmKtlog[0cm]{1999-DEF8}{
  Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; ``Quantum Fields and
  Strings: A Course for Mathematicians.''  Vol. 1--2. With Freed Daniel
  S., Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
  Witten Edward.
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give a more complete example, including the document class you are using. When I use your command definition in a regular document (report) I don't see any extra space, only the skip between lines (natural).

Comment: you have not provided a usable example but there will just be `\parskip`  and the \baselineskip minus the depth of the last row of #2 and the height of the first row of #3. You are also missing `%` from ends of lines. as noted in your previous question if you set `\leftskip` directly in that way any nested lists or centred environments in `#3` will be mis-aligned.

Comment: @JohnKormylo No, the code is under `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

Comment: *What* vertical space?

Comment: Between `[1999-DEF8]` and `[Deligne...`].  I would like the ability to contral the vertical s-pacing between the two lines of text.

Comment: Have found that using `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` after `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` removed the extra spacing between the two paragraphs.

Comment: What is the usefulness of having `\parbox` in this implementation ?

Comment: @egreg - It seems like people are starting to use ExplSyntax just to avoid adding spaces.  I suppose you could do the same thing with a tikzpicture, except the definitions would be local.  Would `\@bsphack` `\@esphack` work as well?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Those commands are for controlling printed spaces, not for code.

Comment: In other words, if all you wanted to do is avoid printing spaces, yes.